# Socket synchronous receive

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking

I have a weird problem occuring at times.
I have a synchronous socket that I connect to and send data to fine.

```
do
{
    try
    {
        // blocking
        int bytesRead = sender.Receive(bytesReceived);

        // process the received bytes
    }
    catch (SocketException soex)
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Socket exception..." +Environment.NewLine+"[Code: {0}] {1}",soex.ErrorCode,soex.Message));
    }
}
while (sender.Poll(1500, SelectMode.SelectRead) && sender.Available > 0);
```

I don't want to stay in the Receive forever since it is blocking, so that is why I put a poll with a time to wait for a response for the packets to get time to come onto the wire and along with the Available, I can break when there's no more data for real.

The problem I am getting is that the while (in the do-while) returns false, when client.Available > 0 is FALSE (it has bytes)
I put a Debug.WriteLine after the while to print out how many available bytes are available and I get a number.

Any idea? I'm puzzled.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `ReceiveAsync` ?

Comment: Which is the expression that returns false? `sender.Poll(1500, SelectMode.SelectRead)` or `sender.Available > 0`?

Comment: Maybe you have bytes when you are on the debugger but not when the expression was executed?

Comment: When I increase the Poll timeout, to 5000, it works fine. I was hoping to reduce the wait time to as low as possible.

L.B what's the advantage of the asynchronous version in this case? just curious and also do you have a link where there's a well defined implementation? I can't seem to find one on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `sender.Poll` returns false, but still returns data to be read. Maybe you could just change your *while*-condition to `sender.Available > 0` and call `sender.Poll` inside the loop.

**EDIT**:
Maybe this is enough (pseudo-code):

```
int length;
do {
  length = socket.Read(buffer);
  // process "buffer"
} while (length > 0);
```

You may need to set a socket timeout to prevent the Read call from blocking too long.